# C/C++ struct for bit flags (bit order)

Tags: c++, c, struct, bitwise-operators, bit

I'm trying to define a common structure for holding bit flags on an 8-bit, single byte record to avoid cluttering my code with bit-wise operations.  Here's what I've got:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t v1:1; // Bit 7
    uint8_t v2:1; // Bit 6
    uint8_t v3:1; // Bit 5
    uint8_t v4:1; // Bit 4
    uint8_t v5:1; // Bit 3
    uint8_t v6:1; // Bit 2
    uint8_t v7:1; // Bit 1
    uint8_t v8:1; // Bit 0
} record8x1_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t v1:2; // Bits 7-6
    uint8_t v2:2; // Bits 5-4
    uint8_t v3:2; // Bits 3-2
    uint8_t v4:2; // Bits 1-0
} record8x2_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t v1:4; // Bits 7-4
    uint8_t v2:4; // Bits 3-0
} record8x4_t;

typedef union
{
    uint8_t value;
    record8x1_t s1;
    record8x2_t s2;
    record8x4_t s4;
} record8_t;


record8_t eight_bits;
eight_bits.value = 0x0D;

std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v1 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v2 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v3 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v3 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v4 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v4 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v5 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v5 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v6 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v6 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v7 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v7 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s1.v8 = " << (int)eight_bits.s1.v8 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s2.v1 = " << (int)eight_bits.s2.v1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s2.v2 = " << (int)eight_bits.s2.v2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s2.v3 = " << (int)eight_bits.s2.v3 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s2.v4 = " << (int)eight_bits.s2.v4 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s4.v1 = " << (int)eight_bits.s4.v1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "eight_bits.s4.v2 = " << (int)eight_bits.s4.v2 << std::endl;
```

And here's the output:

```
eight_bits.s1.v1 = 1
eight_bits.s1.v2 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v3 = 1
eight_bits.s1.v4 = 1
eight_bits.s1.v5 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v6 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v7 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v8 = 0

eight_bits.s2.v1 = 1
eight_bits.s2.v2 = 3
eight_bits.s2.v3 = 0
eight_bits.s2.v4 = 0

eight_bits.s4.v1 = 13
eight_bits.s4.v2 = 0
```

I was expecting the bits to be in left to right, high to low order like so **00001101** instead of the opposite **1011000**.  I'm using *g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)* on a *CentOS 6.8* host.

**QUESTION**: Is this a big/little endian thing or compiler dependant?  Is there some sort of *pragma* setting to fix this?

Here's the output that I was expecting:

```
eight_bits.s1.v1 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v2 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v3 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v4 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v5 = 1
eight_bits.s1.v6 = 1
eight_bits.s1.v7 = 0
eight_bits.s1.v8 = 1

eight_bits.s2.v1 = 0
eight_bits.s2.v2 = 0
eight_bits.s2.v3 = 3
eight_bits.s2.v4 = 1

eight_bits.s4.v1 = 0
eight_bits.s4.v2 = 13
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  In C++ this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver Really? C++ doesn't allow union type punning?

Comment: Apart from C++ standard, why do you expect s1.v1 to be put in MSB?

Comment: @NathanOliver - C++.  By undefined do you mean g++ will do it one way other compilers do it a different way?

Comment: @2501: It does for a limited number of cases. Here it is undefined because it violates strict aliasing rules and the members don't share a common initial sequence. They would, though, if the `uint8_t` wasn't included.

Comment: @pinkston00 By undefined I mean undefined.  the program does not have to behave in any set manner.

Comment: @2501 I have not seen a compiler where it produces anything other then the expected behavior it is just something to watch out for as someone, somewhere, could make a compiler that formats your hard drive(think suicide Linux) because you were naughty.

Comment: @pinkston00 though it is in truth undefined, the compiler will tend to optimize code according to the target architecture, which tends to make it a big/little endian issue.  Also, if you play with sizeof(someStruct), you may find uint8_t fields have been optimized into a 32/64-bit memory location. See [pragma pack](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html)

Comment: C++ 9.2.4: "*Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. ... Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others.*". Impl-defined means it is defined in the compiler spec (so very well predictable in each concrete instance).

Comment: Thank you, @RustyX.  That's the answer I needed.  I'm realizing I probably should've dug into the spec before posting what turned out to be a duplicate.  So it sounds like I'm better off using bitwise operations on a regular **uint8_t** value or commenting existing code to warn against porting to a different compiler. K.I.S.S. so I'm going with the later, I don't foresee this code getting compiled by anything different on anything other than CentOS/RHEL anytime soon :)

Comment: @pinkston00 it's not so much about the OS as CPU architecture. I suspect the order to be different on a bigendian CPU.

Comment: @AndyG it doesn't for any cases - in C++ only the most recently-assigned member of a union may be read.

Comment: @M.M: Am I misinterpreting 9.5 [class.union]? 
"Note: One special guarantee
is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout
structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this standard-layout union type
contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of
standard-layout struct members;"

Comment: @AndyG oh yeah, forgot about that. But strict aliasing never comes into unions.

Comment: @M.M: Fair enough. I wrote that from memory before I looked at the standard :-)